# Cygwin not cooperating

Tags: windows, cygwin, path, environment-variables

This is gonna sound very simple for you guys but I've never installed cygwin and the tutorial I used gave no contingency plan for when something goes wrong. I added the path C:\cygwin\bin to my Path and when I try to run ls or pwd from cmd.exe nothing seems to work. What did I do wrong with this install?

Comment: By "adding it to your path", do you mean you did that through the Control Panel?  Did you then start a new copy of `cmd.exe` or whatever it was you were using to run `ls` so it could inherit the new path variable?

Comment: Yep thats exactly what I did

Comment: So what do you get if you type `set path` into `cmd.exe`?  Can you paste it here, please?  I suspect you may have a typo that could be hard to spot.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Alex>set path
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Com
mon Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Window
s\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Windows\System32\W
indowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Sh
ared\Windows Live
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Answer (score 1):

You have a spurious extra space in your path setting just before the `C:\cygwin\bin` entry:  `...wsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Program Files\Com...`.  Do you see it now?

Comment: Okay thanks! I wasnt getting why it didn't work. Can you give an explanation of why this has to be set with no spaces?

Comment: Because pathnames on Windows can have spaces and the parsing algorithm is really simple.  It just assumes anything between semicolons must be a directory name, spaces and all.

Comment: @user1669657 Glad I was able to help.  If this answers your question, I'd appreciate an upvote and an accept.

Answer (score 0):

The Cygwin installer should be creating a shortcut for a Cygwin prompt. You shouldn't need to be changing your PATH or anything. Actually, if you're using a recent Cygwin, the default terminal program is now `mintty`. If really necessary (though it shouldn't be), you can manually create a shortcut that runs `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe`.

Comment: True, but it should work fine if you put `C:\Cygwin\bin` on your path and run the Cygwin stuff from `cmd.exe`.  You don't have to use their shortcut and `bash` starts faster if you don't.